# Смена 1 блока на другой при помощи JS

Tags: javascript

К примеру:

```
< span id="block1>
что то там ля ля ля

< a onclick="нужная мне функция"> < button>Клик< /button>
</span>
< span id="block2">

Что то на испанском

< /span>
```

В итоге мне надо что бы вместо block1 появился block2 а block1 исчез)

С JS настолько сильно далек,что не могу даже написать самую простую функцию(

Comment: Пожалуй, Вы рано взялись за JS. Если хотите писать веб-сайты, стоит ещё попрактиковаться в чистом HTML и CSS. Не в обиду, просто рекомендация - Москва не сразу строилась)

Comment: Та мне на деле только это и надо. Просто я не кодер. И это на деле мне не нужно. Чисто 1 функция нужна

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под словом "исчез"? Удаление из DOM или просто изменение видимости?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('block1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('block2').innerHTML
```

Comment: если функция то 

replaceBlock = (r_id, b_id) => {
    return document.getElementById(r_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML
}